# Numpy/Pandas: Error converting ndarray to series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have the ndarray "diffTemp":

```
diffTemp = np.diff([df.Temp])
```

Where Temp are temperature values whose differences I compute using the difference operator. In this case using print() I get:

```
print(diffTemp) = [[-0.16 -0.05]]
```

To convert it into a column vector I use:

```
diffTemp = diffTemp.transpose()
```

And then convert is from ndarray into Series using:

```
diffTemp = pd.Series([diffTemp])
```

(This allows me later to concatenate diffTime with its corresponding Series dates (diffDates).)

Unfortunately this outputs that diffTemp is:

```
print(diffTemp) = 0    [[-0.16000000000000014], [-0.05000000000000071]]
```

If I instead use (i.e. without hard brackets [ ]), such that instead:

```
diffTemp = pd.Series(diffTemp)
```

I instead get the error message:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Totally new to Python and have tried google the last few days without any success. Any help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to convert a two-dimensional array into a 1-dimensional series. Notice that there are two brackets around [[-0.16 -0.05]]. You can write the following to get back a series by just grabbing the 1-d array that you want:

```
diffTemp = pd.Series(diffTemp[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is brilliant, I had lost track of the dimensions